# Exchange server 2003 generates event logs daily at 5:00 pm. After restarting the service Microsoft Exchange information store everything works

Tags: exchange-2003

We have exchange server 2003. Daily at 5:00 PM getting event id - 9690. I have already archive  heavy mailbox email. but still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are running Exchange Standard, and have exceeded the database size limit, and Exchange is stopping the message store. If you have exceeded the size limit of 16GB, and have not made the registry change to enable the 75GB limit, you can find it below. You must be on Exchange SP2 for this change.

If you have already made this change, and have exceeded 75GB, you have no options but to reduce mailbox sizes, or migrate to a new version of Exchange where these limits are not present.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912375

How big is your database and what version of Exchange are you running?